# The best way to manage refresh tokens server-side

Tags: mysql, redis, jwt, token

I am using `redis` to store it in `userId`:`refreshToken`.

However, this method prevents one user from logging into multiple devices.

So I try to change it to the format of `userId_accessToken`:`refreshToken`.

However, this method should be `del->insert` whenever the `access token` or `refresh token` is changed.

So I'm debating between two methods.

1. Save it in redis as above.
2. Save in DB as [id, userId, refreshToken, accessToken, expDate].

In mysql, I will create a `cron` that will delete it after the expDate.
In redis, It will apply `ttl` when creating it.
What's a better way?

Our server's memory is 3969424.
Database uses `rds` and `mysql`.

If there's another good way, that's great too!

Comment: Since both methods can solve the problem, if I were you, I would choose whichever is simpler to implement

Comment: @wuhoyt thank you! Which of the two methods I have suggested is safer? I'm worried that frequent I/O will happen.

Comment: well it depends, what you mean by safer? if you mean not losing data, I think there is binlog in mysql and aof file in redis, I mean they can deal with failures. Mysql will cache data in memory for IO case, change buffer pool size to a relative large number(default 128M) I think it will reduce IO, probably to only one IO in a second

Comment: @wuhoyt Thank you so much for your kind reply! I asked because I had a db lock in the past due to frequent I/O!

Comment: @wuhoyt This is because I need to update when access_token is changed or refresh_token is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose whichever is simpler to implement

and another thought, you can use MyRocks engine to automatic delete old keys

[MyRocks-ttl](https://github.com/facebook/mysql-5.6/wiki/Time-to-Live-%28TTL%29)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT, b INT, c INT, PRIMARY KEY (a), KEY(b)) ENGINE=ROCKSDB COMMENT "ttl_duration=3600;";
```

> In the above examples, we set ttl_duration to 3600 meaning that we expect rows older than 3600 seconds to be removed from the database.

Comment: Everyone may wish to Google Search for MyRocks depreciate/deprecated BEFORE choosing anything to do with MyRocks.  Looks like it is going or gone away for most versions